# Кнопка в tkinter вылезает в другое окно

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

[image: Не знаю, я новичок, пытался гуглить, но не нашёл ответ, помогите]
Вообще не знаю что делать, уже всё перепробовал (из того, что я знаю)

```
def checker():
    pas = password.get()
    log = login.get()
    if log == 'python' and pas == 'nohtyp':
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('400x400')
        root.title('Панель управления проектами')
        la1 = Label(text='')
        la1.grid()
        bu1 = Button(text='Калькулятор', command=calc)
        bu1.grid()
        root.mainloop()
    else:
        err = m.showerror(title="Access denied", message="you can't to enter to panel")
```

...

```
wig = Tk();
wig.geometry('200x200');
wig.title('Пропуск в панель управления');
login1 = Label(text='Login:');
login1.grid();
login1.place(x=80, y=0);
password1 = Label(text='Password:');
password1.grid();
password1.place(x=70, y=40);
login = Entry();
login.grid();
login.place(x=40, y=20);
password = Entry(show='*');
password.grid();
password.place(x=40, y=60);
checkbut = Button(text='check',command=checker,bg='red',activebackground='red3');
checkbut.grid();
checkbut.place(x=80, y=100);
wig.mainloop();
```

Comment: Будет круто, если ты скопируешь проблемный участок кода в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы создаете виджеты без указания родительского окна, они крепятся к основному окну (тому, которое вы создали первым). В дочерних окнах нужно указывать родительское окно:

```
root = Tk()

...

bu1 = Button(root, text='Калькулятор', command=calc)
```

Также советую создавать дочерние окна как объекты класса `Toplevel`, а не `Tk`, иначе у вас будут проблемы с переменными tk (`IntVar` и т.д.), ну и вызов `mainloop` должен быть только один (у главного окна - в вашем случае это `wig`).